# Changing a column type from a Pandas dataframe to datetime changes the values on the other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am loading data from .csv files to Pandas dataframes. The data is from meteorological stations and has a "date and time" column. The problem arises when converting that column from string to datetime type, for some reason the data from other columns also changes to zeros or other values that I do not understand.

```
# first load the data
dique_aforador = pd.read_csv(obs_path+'Altura_diqueAforador_Estacion-4216.csv', sep=';', low_memory=False, skip_blank_lines=True, header=1).dropna(how='all')

# Look at the data
dique_aforador

    Fecha y Hora    Altura [m]
0   19/12/2019 13:00    0.00
1   19/12/2019 14:00    0.00
2   19/12/2019 15:00    0.00
3   19/12/2019 16:00    0.00
4   19/12/2019 17:00    0.00
... ... ...
14778   08/02/2022 15:00    1.34
14779   08/02/2022 16:00    1.34
14780   08/02/2022 17:00    1.33
14781   08/02/2022 18:00    1.33
14782   08/02/2022 19:00    1.33

# Plot the data as is
dique_aforador.plot(x='Fecha y Hora', rot=45)
```

[image]

```
# But when I change the 'Fecha y Hora' column to datetime
dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'])

# This happens:
dique_aforador.plot(x='Fecha y Hora', rot=45)
```

[image]

Looks like several entries of the `Altura [m]` column are replaced by zero or other random values and I do not understand what is happening. I have also tried other equivalent ways of doing the conversion to datetime and I get the same issue with all of them (using the `.astype('datetime64[ns]')` method, adding `parse_dates=['Fecha y Hora']` when loading the data, etc.). This also happens when using meteorological station data from other sources, so I think it is not dataset-dependent and has to do with something related to the datetime conversion. Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: In your data table the last date is `08/02/2022` but in your 2nd graph the x-axis extends beyond 2022-09 which means that some dates are from the future. I think you need to first make sure that the dates in their string forms are in the right format. #1 `dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'].min()` and `dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'].max()` give you the max and min date as long as the format is right even if they are strings. #2 `(dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'].str.len() != 16).sum()` tells you how many rows have a different string length.

Comment: Also I suggest you to sort your dataframe before each of the two plotting. `dique_aforador=dique_aforador.sort_values('Fecha y Hora')`

Comment: @RaymondKwok Thank you for your help. I believe the problem came from Pandas assuming that the dates were in US format (day and month flipped), it is now fixed with the addition of `infer_date_format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `infer_date_format` option to `pandas.to_datetime`?

Something like this:

`dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(dique_aforador['Fecha y Hora'], infer_datetime_format=True)`

Pandas can take the first value in your date field and infer the remaining from it

Comment: This worked, thank you! I believe the problem came from Pandas assuming that the dates were in US format (month and day flipped), and somehow `infer_date_format` solved that